# Group computation between rows on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
> df.head()

    channel   sym   quant      value    when
0   online    FTR   items   0.000515  before
1   video     FTR   items   0.000329   after
2   online    PAC   items   1.839338  before
3   video     PAC   items   2.355360   after
4   online    EPM   items   0.000947  before
5   test      EPM   items   0.000774   after
6   online    CLC   deals   0.000681  before
7   test      CLC   deals   0.000808   after
8   video     CLC   deals   0.000808   after
9   online    CPC   deals   1.620517  before
```

I am hoping to learn the difference in value from `before` to  `after` for each unique combination of `channel`, `sym` and `quant`. How can I do this in Pandas?

I tried with:

```
def my_func(x):
  after_value  = x.ix[x['when']=='after','value']
  before_value = x.ix[x['when']=='before','value']
  return  after_value - before_value

df.groupby(['channel', 'sym', 'quant']).apply(my_func)
```

but I got:

```
channel  sym  quant    
online   CLC  deals  6    NaN
                     8    NaN
         CPC  deals  10   NaN
         EPM  items  4    NaN
         FTR  items  0    NaN
         PAC  items  2    NaN
test     CLC  deals  7    NaN
         EPM  items  5    NaN
video    CLC  deals  9    NaN
         FTR  items  1    NaN
         PAC  items  3    NaN
```

which does not give me the desired result.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't seem to include any combinations of channel, sym, quant that have both a before and after value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to group by `['sym', 'quant']`? If so, then if you change the sign of the value whereever `when` equals `before`:

```
In [199]: df['value'] *= np.where(df['when'] == 'before', -1, 1)

In [200]: df
Out[200]: 
  channel  sym  quant     value    when
0  online  FTR  items -0.000515  before
1   video  FTR  items  0.000329   after
2  online  PAC  items -1.839338  before
3   video  PAC  items  2.355360   after
4  online  EPM  items -0.000947  before
5    test  EPM  items  0.000774   after
6  online  CLC  deals -0.000681  before
7    test  CLC  deals  0.000808   after
8   video  CLC  deals  0.000808   after
9  online  CPC  deals -1.620517  before
```

then you can find the difference by taking a sum:

```
In [202]: df.groupby(['sym', 'quant'])['value'].agg('sum')
Out[202]: 
sym  quant
CLC  deals    0.000935
CPC  deals   -1.620517
EPM  items   -0.000173
FTR  items   -0.000186
PAC  items    0.516022
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Be careful that each group (with same `sym` and `quant`) contains only one `before` and `after` row; otherwise the sum might not be what you want. For example, if there is an `after` row, but no `before`, then the sum will equal the `after` value, as if the `before` value is 0. Indeed, that's what happens if you group by `channel`, `sym` and `quant`, since each group only contains one row:

```
In [201]: df.groupby(['channel', 'sym', 'quant'])['value'].agg('sum')
Out[201]: 
channel  sym  quant
online   CLC  deals   -0.000681
         CPC  deals   -1.620517
         EPM  items   -0.000947
         FTR  items   -0.000515
         PAC  items   -1.839338
test     CLC  deals    0.000808
         EPM  items    0.000774
video    CLC  deals    0.000808
         FTR  items    0.000329
         PAC  items    2.355360
Name: value, dtype: float64
```